# Pyramid Storage Backend for S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyramid

I'm looking for a good Pyramid custom storage backend for use with Amazon S3. I've been googling around but can't seem to find much. Could someone please give some suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Boto](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html) is the goto library for interacting with AWS within any python application.

Comment: I happily use Boto in Pyramid for saving files.

Answer (score 0):

[pyramid_storage](https://pythonhosted.org/pyramid_storage/) provides out of the box ability to store uploaded files locally and at S3